# Settings.settingsに保存している独自構造体の設定がちょっとしたことで消えるのを回避したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

## 開発環境

- Windows 10(64bit)
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- C#+WPF

## 問題が発生する手順

- 次のように独自の構造体を作成
  [image: クラスの説明]
- 独自構造体を保存するため、Settings.Designer.csを編集(下記の記述を追加)
  [image: 編集内容]
- ところが、Settings.settingsが編集された場合、上記編集箇所(独自構造体保存ロジック)が吹き飛んでしまう
- 現状ではGitでdiffを取りつつ修正しているが、面倒で仕方ないので何とかしたい

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings.Designer.cs`には[`partial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/wbx7zzdd.aspx)修飾子が指定されています。
このようなデザイナー生成型をカスタマイズする場合は、適当な場所に`Settings.cs`のようなファイルを作成して

```
namespace ******.Properties
{
    partial class Settings
    {
    }
}
```

と同名の`partial`型定義を作成します。このファイルはデザイナーに変更されず、ビルドするとカスタムツール生成部分と併せて1つの型になります。

また問題の構造体を`Settings`を含むプロジェクトではなく、別のプロジェクトに定義している場合は`Settings.settings`のデザイナーでも「参照...」メニューから選択することが出来ます。

Comment: こちらの方法で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

一度ビルドを行ってからであれば、`Settings.settings`デザイナーで定義した型を選択できます。（正確には、型名を入力できます。）

Comment: それをやってみようとしたのですが無理でした……